# What is the Scala version from?

Tags: scala

In some jar repository, I found these jar packages with themselves' version and Scala's version. [spark-excel](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.crealytics/spark-excel) for example.

So where does the Scala version come from? Is it the Scala to build the project?

Comment: It is for compatibility. Meaning those JARs only support the given Scala version. For example none of these would work with ```Scala 2.13 ``` as they only provide support up to 2.12

Comment: And yeah, that was the **Scala** version used to build that jar.